# BadTLP PCIe Bus Error in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04, pci, lspci

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my system, and I'm getting PCIe bus errors on bootup. These errors also occurred on my Linux mint 19 install, so I'm worried it might be something with the hardware. That or the kernel itself. Here's the log:

```
23:16:26 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:    [ 6] BadTLP                
23:16:26 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:    [ 6] BadTLP                
23:16:26 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                 
23:16:26 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:   device [8086:9d13] error status/mask=00000041/00002000
23:16:26 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
23:16:26 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:    [ 7] BadDLLP               
23:16:26 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                 
23:16:26 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:   device [8086:9d13] error status/mask=00000081/00002000
23:16:26 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
23:16:24 systemd: Failed to start VirtualBox Web Service.
23:16:13 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                 
23:16:13 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                 
23:16:13 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:   device [8086:9d13] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
23:16:13 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

I've also been having issues with internet access dropping out intermittently and high latency. So I want to figure out if these errors might have something to do with that.

Please tell me if there's any more information I need to provide. Thanks!

Comment: I'm experiencing something similar - did you ever resolve this?